# Mostrar el primer registro de una tabla relacionada - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo una tabla que se llama productos y esta relacionada con una tabla que se llama medidas y donde esta los precios.
Bien lo que necesito es que hago un `foreach` con todos los productos, pero necesito a la vez sacar el precio del primer registro que corresponda a la id del producto de la tabla medidas.

**Obtengo los productos del siguiente modo desde el controlador**

```
$this->productos = Producto::
                join('brands', 'productos.id_brand', '=', 'brands.id')
                ->select('productos.*', 'brands.nombre')
                ->latest('id')
                ->limit(6)
                ->where('productos.estado', 1)
                ->get();
```

**Luego con con foreach saco los prodcutos en la vista**

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)
.....
@endforeach
```

**Estoy intentando sacar el primer registro que coincide con la tabla medidas**

```
@foreach ($pro->medidas as $elp)
   {{ $elp->precio }}
@endforeach <span>€</span>
```

Pero de este modo me sacas toda la relación y necesito sacar el primer resultado, ya que sera el de menor importe.

Como puedo hacerlo?

**Modelo productos**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';

    public function opciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Opcion', 'product_id');
    }
    public function medidas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Medida', 'product_id');
    }
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
    public function complementos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Producto_complemento', 'producto_producto_id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Medidas**

```
class Medida extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'medidas';

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Producto', 'id');
    }
}
```

La tabla `Medidas` es la que lleva las medidas y los precios.

Comment: Podrías publicar un detalle de los modelos "producto", "medidas" y "precios"? Con hacer `$elp->precio()->first()` es suficiente, pero lejos de la manera ideal. Por otro lado, si "precio" ta trae varios resultados, entonces se debería llamar "precios", en plural. Publicá los detalles de los modelos así te orientamos mejor.

Comment: Hola @azeós  ya te publique los modelos, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy un par de soluciones para que entiendas como funciona la cosa. Te recomiendo que leas todas y saques tus propias conclusiones.

Primero para dejar en claro una cosa, vos necesitás traer la medida de *menor importe*, no *la primera*. Si por algún motivo la primera deja de ser la de menor importe estarías en un problema. Entonces, es importante que definas si querés la primera (sin importar cual sea) o si querés la de menor importe, no asumas que son lo mismo.

---

**a. Dejar todo como está y usar [`->first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)**

Si hacés un `foreach ($pro->medidas as $elp)` ya estás trayendo todas las medidas, y vos necesitás solo una.

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)
    <span>{{ $pro->medidas()->orderBy('precio')->first()->precio }}€</span>
@endforeach
```

Lo que se está haciendo es a partir del "producto" actual realizar *una nueva consulta* a la base de datos para pedir la medida con el menor precio.

Es importar marcar la diferencia entre: `medidas->first()` y `medidas()->first()`. En el primero se traen todas las medidas y de esa *colección* se selecciona la primera. En el segundo solo se trae una.

Ahora, esto tiene un problema, y es que por cada producto vas a realizar una *nueva consulta* para traer una medida. Es lo que se conoce como un problema de ["N + 1"](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Es decir, si tenés 10 productos vas a realizar:

- Una consulta para traer los 10 productos.
- 10 consultas (una por cada producto) para traer la primera medida de cada uno.

---

**b. Usar [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) con `->first()`**

Para resolver el problema de generar una nueva consulta por cada producto, podes utilizar [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Básicamente lo que se hace es *antes* de recorrer los productos indicar que además se van a requerir sus medidas. De esa manera se traen todas las medidas en una sola consulta y no una por cada producto.

```
$this->productos = Producto::
    join('brands', 'productos.id_brand', '=', 'brands.id')
    ->select('productos.*', 'brands.nombre')
    ->with(['medidas' => function ($query) { // Eager loading
        // Traemos todas las medidas ordenadas por precio
        $query->orderBy('precio');
    }])->latest('id')
    ->limit(6)
    ->where('productos.estado', 1)
    ->get();
```

Eso va a generar 2 consultas:

- Una para traer todos los productos.
- Otra para traer TODAS las medidas de cada producto.

Como ya tenemos las medidas, al hacer el `foreach` no usamos `medidas()->first()` porque eso generaría una nueva consulta, ahora si usamos `medidas->first()`. Pedimos la primera de todas *las que ya trajimos*.

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)
    <span>{{ $pro->medidas->first()->precio }}€</span>
@endforeach
```

Perfecto, solucionamos el problema de generar una consulta por cada producto. Pero ahora tenemos otro, estamos trayendo TODAS las medidas por cada producto. Lo ideal sería no generar una consulta por cada producto, pero traer solo UNA medida por producto.

---

**c. Usar una relación [`hasOne()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)**

Tenés definida una relación [`hasMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) con respecto a "medidas", lo cual es correcto. Pero el problema es que Eloquent va a armar todas sus consultas esperando más de un resultado, porque es exactamente lo que está especificando esa relación. Como en tu caso vos necesitás un solo resultado, lo que podes hacer es crear una nueva relación determinando justamente eso.

```
public function medidas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Medida', 'product_id');
}

public function medidaDeMenorPrecio()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Medida', 'product_id')->orderBy('precio');
}
```

Una vez definida la relación, combinamos la respuesta anterior:

```
$this->productos = Producto::
    join('brands', 'productos.id_brand', '=', 'brands.id')
    ->select('productos.*', 'brands.nombre')
    ->with('medidaDeMenorPrecio') // Eager loading
    ->latest('id')
    ->limit(6)
    ->where('productos.estado', 1)
    ->get();
```

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)
    <span>{{ $pro->medidaDeMenorPrecio->precio }}€</span>
@endforeach
```

La única desventaja de este método, es que seguís necesitando una consulta extra para traer las medidas. Lo ideal (es relativo, depende de que otras cosas estés haciendo), sería realizar una sola consulta.

---

**d. Hacer un [`leftJoin()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)**

Volvemos a lo básico, nos olvidamos de Eloquent y hacemos un JOIN con la tabla de medidas para traer la de menor precio.

```
$this->productos = Producto::
    join('brands', 'productos.id_brand', '=', 'brands.id')
    ->leftJoin(
        'medidas',
        'medidas.id',
        '=',
        DB::raw("(
            SELECT id
            FROM medidas
            WHERE medidas.product_id = productos.id
            ORDER BY precio
            LIMIT 1
        )")
    )->select('productos.*', 'brands.nombre', 'medidas.precio')
    ->with('medidaDeMenorPrecio') // Eager loading
    ->latest('id')
    ->limit(6)
    ->where('productos.estado', 1)
    ->get();
```

Ese JOIN trae una sola medida, la de menor precio. Una sola consulta para traer todos los productos y su menor precio.

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)
    <span>{{ $pro->precio }}€</span>
@endforeach
```

La desventaja es que hay que hacer toda una consulta a mano y al no usar Eloquent, no tenemos acceso al objeto `Medida`, pero si solo necesitás el campo precio, no veo el problema.

---

En fin, te dejo las opciones. Hay muchas otras formas de hacerlo y hay otras cosas que optimizar o considerar. Pero me parece que como panorama general es suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Seria mejor que uses solo `QueryBuilder` o solo `Modelo` en este caso es mejor modelo para lo cual tienes que agregar algunas líneas de código

**Producto**

```
....
    protected $table='producto';//[tabla de BD] puede no ser necesario
    protected $primaryKey='id';//[PK tabla de BD] puede no ser necesario
    public $timestamps=false;//[Fechas de Registro] puede no ser necesario

    public function brands(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Brands','id_brand','id');//Decimos que hay un relación con Modelo Brands, M - 1
    }
....
```

**Brands**

```
....
    protected $table='brands';//[tabla de BD] puede no ser necesario
    protected $primaryKey='id';//[PK tabla de BD] puede no ser necesario
    public $timestamps=false;//[Fechas de Registro] puede no ser necesario

    public function productos() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Producto','id','id_brand');
    }
....
```

Y ahora como obtenemos los datos?, de esta manera

**Solo Producto**

```
$pro = Producto::find($id);// funcionan todos los métodos
```

**Agregando Brand**

```
$pro = Producto::with('brands')->find($id);
```

**Acceder a los datos**

```
@foreach ($pro->brands as $elp)
   {{ $elp->brands->marca }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola gracias por u respuesta, pero no se como me puede ayudar esto a mostrar un solo resultado, algunas veces utilizo las relaciones, pero no siempre me funcionan de una forma correcta, por eso hice los `joins` (por ejemplo).

Comment: puede no ser la mejor forma ya que obtienes todos los atributos tanto del `producto` como de su relacion `brands (medidas)`, funcionan bastante bien las relaciones directas, `M-M , M-1, 1-1` pero si son tablas lejanas, o quieres datos específicos seria mejor que uses `DB::table('producto')->select()->get()`, la consulta será mas rápida,

Comment: Hola @manrrique meneses yaranga he probado lo que dices para ver si lo que hice en su momento funcionaba de este modo y nada, por el motivo que sea las relaciones no funcionan 100% bien. Pero me gustaria poder solucionar el problema que tengo ahora de sacar el primer registro, puedes ayudarme por favor